# A possibly erroneous bounty auto-award message? I thought I already awarded it, but auto-award notification says it gave the full amount

Tags: support, bounties, notifications

Third time's a charm! Starting at +100 for my first bounty on [Reference request (explaining) how optical correlators combine light from multiple telescopes to produce ultra-high resolution interferometric images?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44591/7982) my third bounty's minimum available was +400 due to anti-gaming measures I believe.

It worked, I got a great answer and I am pretty sure that hours ago I awarded the +400 bounty myself. The answer now shows with an awarded +400 bounty.

However, I just got a notification:

> INBOX
>
> all items
>
> Astronomy Stack Exchange bounty auto-awarded 20 mins ago
>
> Your bounty on question "Reference request (explaining) how optical correlators combine light from multiple telescopes to produce ultra-high resolution interferometric images?" has expired - answer auto-selected.

The reasons I think this might be an erroneous message are:

1. I seem to remember awarding it manually several hours ago
2. It's the full amount of +400, I seem to remember that the auto-selection awards half of the bounty as a sort-of compromise.

What actually happened here?

---

[image]

Comment: Did you confirm awarding the bounty after clicking the button? The records show you did *not* award the bounty yourself and the system did it for you. (And it awards the full amount if you accepted the answer during the bounty period.)

Comment: @animuson thanks! How does one confirm that. I remember seeing that the bounty had expired and was in the 24 hour grace period, thinking "oh time to award it" then awarding it. I am then *pretty sure* the bounty message disappeared. Beyond that, what mechanisms for *confirming an award* exist? **update:** I looked for the timestamp for "accept" in the history of the Q and A posts and can't find one. I wonder if I missed by a centimeter and clicked accept instead of award? If that triggers auto-award of full amount and removes the banner, that would explain everything!

Comment: For maximum visibility I usually hold out to accept in the last few days, and occasionally until the grace period. I then accept the answer at a later date. It now seems very possible that I'd accidentally clicked the wrong button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an erroneous message.

> 1. I seem to remember awarding it manually several hours ago

Your [accept history on the site](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/7982/uhoh?tab=activity&sort=accepts) shows that you accepted the answer about 22 hours before you asked this question. It's quite possible that you clicked on the accept button instead of the bounty award button, as you noted in your comments.

> 2. It's the full amount of +400, I seem to remember that the auto-selection awards half of the bounty as a sort-of compromise.

Per the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/377214), there's a special rule for automatic awards where the author has offered the bounty and accepted an answer:

> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was posted after the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full bounty.

That explains why the automatic award was the full amount instead of half. (Of note, for bounties offered by users other than the question author, the answer to automatically award is still selected in the usual manner - the one with the highest score out of answers posted after the bounty started with a score of at least 2 - but if the selected answer happens to have been accepted by the author, it will get the full bounty.)

Comment: Yes this is almost certainly what happened. I didn't know about the special rule be cause I usually make sure a few days pass after acceptance before I accept. Mystery solved and learned something new. *Thanks!*

Comment: ...after *awarding*...